# C# Event causing Session Variable Error ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, events

So I basically have an event that fired off when my connected cash receiver takes in money, and I'm using a session variable to store the index of the bill inserted, and I get an error that says: [image: Session Variable error]

My session variables work everywhere else correctly except here. Any idea why this is happening? Everywhere I look online it tells me to set up my session correctly which it is if my other ones work fine. This event is fired when on a view page with no other methods running. Any help is appreciated. If the information is too vague I apologize, I will provide more information if you need it to help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Edit: Stack
[image: call stack]

This is the event being fired where the SetString is causing the error.

```
 void validator_OnCredit(object sender, CreditArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Credited bill#: {0}", e.Index);

        switch (e.Index)
        {
            case 1:
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "1");
                break;
            default:
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", e.Index.ToString());
                break;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Comment: can you post the stack? what type of page is it (Generic Web handler)?

Comment: It's a razor page, regular MVC stuff.

Comment: @timkly I edited my post and put up a screen shot of the call stack and some details on the broken session. I hope this is what you had in mind, otherwise I apologize

Answer (score 2):

3) Updated Answer
Session Namespace Reference for beta(s) or RC1

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Session
```

Session Namespace Reference from CORE 1.0

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
```

2) Updated Answer - If accessing a session outside the controller then you need to inject the session into it as follows

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    public TestClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void SetString()
    {
        _session.SetString("Test", "Ben Rules!");
    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return _session.GetString("Test");
    }
}
```

1) Initial Answer - Incorrect for current scenario... but if session isn't working this is a good place to start

From the error message I assume you are using .NET Core?

If so then the middleware is added sequentially so you need to ensure that your code intitialises [Session Management](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html) first before it uses MVC

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // ...
   services.AddSession();
   // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I have already set up the sessions like that. My other session variables across the program work fine. Its just in this event where it doesn't.

Comment: Actually looking at the signature for the page is that a web form? If so, Web Forms are tied to System.Web will remain in the .NET 4.x framework... which means the MVC app and the Web Forms probably won't be able to share session state

Comment: No it's an asp.net web application. Rc-1

Comment: Can you post up a snippet of the controller?

Comment: Of what specifically in the controller?

Comment: the actual code where you are attempting to get the session object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121504/discussion-between-timkly-and-alfred-shaker).